# Alternate a task Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: scheduled-task, task-scheduler, task-manager, task

I'm looking for a good way to alternate a task within the Windows Task Scheduler.

One Saturday, run Task A. Then the next Saturday, run Task B. Then repeat.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish that within one single Task or the Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: Create two tasks... each one to run every other Saturday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two tasks. Set the Repeat to two weeks.

[image]

Set the start date of task A to one Saturday and the start date of task B to the following Saturday.